# How to add edit delete and delete all items from lists

Tags: jquery

[image]

Good morning how can i add and edit and remove and remove all items from Selectable using buttons and how i can disable buttons after removing all of items.

id of list of items : Selectable
id of button add is btnadd
id of button edit is buttonEdit
id of button remove is buttonDelete
id of button remove all is buttondeleteall

Please help me because i have an exam tomorrow at the University

Comment: You should probably study instead of asking strangers to help you. There is a low of documentation on jQuery and all questions you are asking have been asked before. check out the jquery [.remove()](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) and [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) documentations

Comment: Please if you can send your email to contact you and help me because it is my first time in jquery and I need some help

Comment: to add elements you use `.append()` like `$(".container").append("<li>List item 2</li>");` and to remove it just do `$(".classname").remove();`

Comment: Also, a code snippet of what you've got so far will help with answering the questions you're asking

Comment: Can i send my codes  for you email ?

Comment: You can edit your question and place the relevant code there. So if I can't help you others can.